# Upgrading to Tapestry5.1 Javascript Error

Tags: java, javascript, tapestry

Iam upgrading my app from Tapestry 5.0.18 to 5.1.0.5 and i get following javascript error. I know there was a fix for WaitForPage() for partial ajax responses in 5.1.0.5. But i still keep gettin the java script error. Following is my code.

```
        <table t:id="itemPanel" t:type="CustomSlidingPanel" closed="true"   subject="literal:itemes" blockId="literal:itemPanel_content"    linkToDisplay="New item" actionLink="newitem"   zoneOnAction="itemZone"/>
        <div id="itemPanel_content" style="display: none;">
            <table t:id="itemGrid" t:type="customGrid" source="item"    row="itemRow" clientId="literal:itemGrid"   rowId="itemRow.itemId" add="edit"   include="type, item, price,store,startDate, endDate, ynprimary" inplace="true">
                <t:parameter name="editCell">
                    <t:actionlink t:id="editItem" t:zone="itemZone" t:context="itemRow.id">Edit</t:actionlink>
                </t:parameter>
            </table>
        </div>
        <t:zone t:id="itemZone" visible="false">
            <t:delegate to="itemBlock" />
        </t:zone>
        <t:block t:id="itemBlock">
            <div id="newitemDiv" class="dataEntry"/>
            <div id="itemDivParent">
                <div id="itemDiv" class="dataEntry">
                    <t:form t:id="itemForm" name="itemForm">
                        <t:if test="itemObject.id">
                            <script type="text/javascript">insertDivElement('itemGrid${itemObject.id}','itemDivParent','itemDiv','newitemDiv','8');</script>
                        </t:if>
                        <t:if test="newitem">
                            <script type="text/javascript">createNewDivElement('itemDivParent','itemDiv','newitemDiv');</script>
                        </t:if>
                        <table t:id="itemComponent" t:type="item"   itemObject="itemObject"/>
                        <div style="width: 50%" align="center">
                            <input  t:id="saveitem" t:type="Submit" class="button" value="Save" />&nbsp; <input type="button" class="button" value="Cancel" onClick="hideDivs('itemDivParent','itemDiv','newitemDiv');" />&nbsp; <t:if test="itemImported" negate="true">
                                <input t:id="deleteitem" t:type="SubmitContext" class="button"  value="Delete" t:context="itemObject.id" /> &nbsp;</t:if>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                    </t:form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </t:block>
```

Here is the error message that i get. Looks like something wrong with "Tapestry.waitForPage(event)" which is in Tapestry.js. Can some one help?

```
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 197
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:8080/ItemEntry?itemId=131686
<a id="editItemPrice" onclick="javascript:Tapestry.waitForPage(event);" href="itementry.edititemprice/6578">Edit</a>
```

Comment: Maybe it's only a browser-caching problem. I had that once after upgrading Tapestry that the old scripts where causing problems. After clearing my cache it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might be related to the [combine scripts setting](http://tapestry.apache.org/configuration.html#Configuration-tapestry.combinescripts) as [discussed on the mailing list](http://tapestry.1045711.n5.nabble.com/T5-1-0-5-Tapestry-is-undefined-JavaScript-error-on-form-submit-td2393118.html). Set -Dtapestry.combine-scripts=false as a VM argument or add this to your AppModule:

```
public static void contributeApplicationDefaults(final MappedConfiguration<String, String> configuration) {
    configuration.add(SymbolConstants.COMBINE_SCRIPTS, "false");
}
```

Do you have a reason for not upgrading to 5.3 though? It has a bunch of improvements over 5.1.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We are upgrading release by release. Where do i set Dtapestry.combine-scripts=false?

Comment: set it as a VM argument where you start your app as -Dtapestry.combine-scripts=false or add it to your appmodule like I show in my altered answer.

Comment: Have added to appmodule and it didn't work. I have also cleared the browser cache and no use. Any other help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have a live example I can have a look at. Sounds like a firebug debug session could be useful. Also, is it browser specific or does it happen in all browsers?